# I2C clock frequency variations

Tags: pic, i2c

I am using an I2C peripheral in PIC18 series running at 100 kHz and I have used pull up resistors of 4.7 k\$\Omega\$ in the process. I then loaded a code with continuous write operation of EEPROM and viewed the SCL line in the scope. The SCL line does not stay always at 100 kHz. It varies from 100 kHz and some times jumps from 24 kHz to 50 kHz and reaches up to 100 kHz...never goes beyond that.

What should be done to  make the SCL line stable at 100kHz? Will changing the pullup resistor make up the loss?

Comment: What else is the micro doing? Is the I2C interrupt-driven? Are there other interrupts that may override it? If not, are there functions going on that could cause the I2C function to be delayed (EG some function that will sometimes take a long time to return)?

Comment: Which I2C peripheral?  What issues are being caused by the "instability"?

Comment: You are continuously writing to EEPROM?  Check the EEPROM datasheet and see it has a limited number of lifetime writes.  If you write it continuously, then it will wear out quickly.

Comment: Well the slave is just disconnected and i checked only the transmitting signals from SCL whether the clock is stable or not.

Comment: Im using  pic18f26j50 controller.

Comment: How do you measure the clock frequency? Is the measured frequency averaged over multiple bytes? Or can you see, on the scope, that some bytes are send with clock at 100kHz, whereas other bytes are transmitted ad lower clock frequencies?

Comment: Yes..im using techtronix scope.Im viewing the pulse in that instrument.Will the clock stretching will cause problems? Rather than slowing down.

Comment: Depends on what you observe. Clock stretching should only delay transmission of the next byte. But each byte should be transmitted with the normal clock frequency, so you should observe 100kHz then. Maybe you can add an image of the scope so we see what you observe?

Comment: Put some delay after I2C initialization. specially after assigning value of SSPADD.

Answer (score 2):

[Clock stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Clock_stretching_using_SCL) is allowed with I2C.

This could be the reason for the behaviour. What happens when you transfer data at say 20kHz - do you see such lengthened pulses as well or do they disappear?

Comment: Well i have not tried that,i just tried connecting pull up resistors and checked the SCL line.I have not either connected the eeprom chip too.

Comment: Is there any other code running or just the I2C code? Could it be you are outputting something to UART or do some calculations in the background?

Comment: No.Just I2c write is on the flow

Comment: L.Hi..i did some experiments with scope and the chip is working fine in range when i gave 20khz.I see small deviations in between 19-17khz in between.When i gave 50khz..it shows jumps between 34khz and 49khz.And when i reach back to 100khz..it jumps between 54 and 100khz.

Comment: Well only one device(slave) is connected on the bus now.Could that be because of clock stretching.

Comment: Put it into reset, you should see the results immediately. You can also do the following if you think it's your code: Toggle a pin immediately before you start the I2C write. After it's finished, toggle that pin again. Make sure interrupts are disabled (except for those that you need for I2C if any).

Comment: Do you use the hardware I2C module or a software implementation?

Comment: Its a Hardware implementation

Comment: @Rookie91  Related [question about I2C clock stretching (with oscilloscope screenshots)](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145262/how-long-big-is-an-i2c-acknowledge).